# Macro Vlookup Multiple condition Type Mismatch error

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am working on a Excel VBA Macro that gets the id of a response from another sheet.

I am getting Error 13 "Type Mismatch" from the VLookup:

```
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim LastColumn As Integer
    Dim rw As Long, x As Range, x1 As Range
    Dim extwbk As Workbook, twb As Workbook


    Sub Job_Res()
    LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    '----------SET RES ID-----------------------------
    Set twb = Workbooks.Open("C:\DM\excel_files\jobs.xlsx")
    Set extwbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\DM\excel_files\RefRes.xlsx")
    Set x = extwbk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:D")

    With twb.Sheets("Sheet1")
        MsgBox "OK"
        For rw = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            .Cells(rw, 11) = Application.VLookup(.Cells(rw, 11).Value + .Cells(rw, 1).Value, x, 2, False)
        Next rw

    End With

    extwbk.Close savechanges:=False

    End Sub
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Side note: Safer to use Application.WorksheetFunction

Answer (score 0):

error is caused by this line:

```
.Cells(rw, 11) = Application.VLookup(.Cells(rw, 11).Value + .Cells(rw, 1).Value, x, 2, False)
```

My guess is that problem is in Arg1 - summation `.Cells(rw, 11).Value + .Cells(rw, 1).Value` cannot be performed correctly. I don't know if you want to add text values (e.g. "a"+"a") or numerical values (1+1). But if you add text and number (1 + "a") it will return error

Also you return result of Vlookup into column used in summation.